# Changing div height after page loads if necessary with Jquery

Tags: javascript, animation, height

For example I have 3 pages: 
page1 with `<div id="header" height="460">`, 
page2 with `<div id="header" height="100">`, 
page3 with `<div id="header" height="100">`.

On the first page1 I have the height set to 460px, but when I change it to any other page(for example page2) it should load the page and then animate it from 460px to 100px, after that if I click on page3 I want it to recognize that it is already set to 100px and no animation is necessary, however if I click back to page1 it would load page1 and animate back to height 460px.

Thanks in advance

Before I tried to use this:

```
$('#buttonToPage2').click(function(){
    $('#header').animate({height:'100px'}, 500);
});

$('#buttonToPage1').click(function(){
    $('#header').animate({height: '460px'}, 500);
});
```

But it animates before it loads the page.

P.S. 
I am not very well with JQuery or JavaScript for that matter.

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself first? What code do you have?

Comment: When you say animate, do you mean slowly?

Comment: Surely, as you load each page, the div will have the height you want. Maybe I'm mis-understanding your requirements?

Comment: @bulugabob I think what he is trying to achieve is that to animate the DIV[id=header] on the current page based on the height attribute of the of the DIV[id=header] in the previous page

Comment: @manraj82 that's right, but if on the previous page I have the same height, you won't see the animation. I hope I make it somewhat clear.

Comment: @Pride if thats the case,you might not get the desired result using just javascript bcos you might run into some problems.Your best bet is to store the URL either in a cookie or a server variable.Set the height of the DIV of the current page to the height of the DIV from the stored URL.Then animate the DIV with the height you need.And you need to the animation bit on the document.ready of each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old question I had. At the time I was not familiar with AJAX. I wanted smooth transitions from one page to another.

At the time I somehow wanted to pass previous page information to next, but what I really needed was pushState API and perhaps a front-end framework like Angular or Vue.

For smaller pages I now use [Page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) to manage state and [Pug.js](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) templating engine, but you can use something like Mustache, Hogan.js or some other templating engine. This way you can do your transitions with JavaScript without reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('#header').animate({
    height: '100px'
 }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Simply call this as soon as the page loaded complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#header).height(100).slideUp();
$(#header).height(460).slideDown();
```

Just call them on `$(document).ready()`